# Overflow-y not working properly on div upon body

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have simple div centered in my container like this:

```
.popup-fixed-info{
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    max-height:80%;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:10;
}
```

on element click I call this simple jQuery function

```
function open_popup(class_to_open) {
  $('.popup-fixed-info').css("visibility", "visible");
  $('.popup-fixed-info').css("opacity", "1");
}
```

The think is that when i scroll the '.popup-fixed-info' div the background is scrolling and not the div itself..

Answer (score 0):

To fix that you need to give the body overflow hidden. Do this in the jQuery:

```
function open_popup(class_to_open) {
  $('.popup-fixed-info').css("visibility", "visible");
  $('.popup-fixed-info').css("opacity", "1");
  $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
}
```

Then remove it when you close the popup.  Whatever function you have for that.

```
$('body').css("overflow", "auto");
```

Comment: It is not working.. I am in angular and everything is inside the body..

Comment: anyway.. i think i need to give up a lot of code to spot the problem.. thanks for the answer though